Not able to run beanshell file for pgp encryption with jmeter for all the request "
I have created benshell code below to enctrypt the json request in jmeter after running give below error message
Error message :
Response code:500
Response message:org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterException: Error invoking bsh method: eval   Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``import org.bouncycastle.openpgp.*; import org.bouncycastle.openpgp.operator.jcaj . . . '' : Unknown class: BouncyCastleProvider
enter image description here
i have Verify Bouncy Castle JAR Files and added added into jmeter/ lib folder
Ensure you have the correct Bouncy Castle JAR files:
Download the JAR Files:
You need at least the following JAR files for PGP functionality:
bcprov-jdk15on-1.69.jar (or a newer version)
bcpkix-jdk15on-1.69.jar (if you are using PGP features)

First of all you need to restart JMeter to pick up any changes in JMeter Classpath.
Also be informed that using Beanshell is some form of a performance anti-pattern especially when it comes to "heavy" operations like cryptography.
Since JMeter 3.1 it's recommended to use JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language for scripting.
More information:

Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?
Encryption and decryption with Groovy -> Using the Bouncy Castle library


This is not a link-only answer, but it almost is. If the links were to die, there'd be very little information left in the answer.
